# force scenario about REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-keys, public-key, known-hosts

everyone know the following message

```
"@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\r",
"@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @\r",
"@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\r",
```

that indicate host remote machine identification was change

now:
we have two machines

and ssh from source machine to target machines is OK

as the following:

```
# ssh Linux_box1
Last login: Tue Aug 27 14:57:51 2019 from linux_box_source
#
```

but now , we want to force scenario that reject ssh and give the message about `EMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED`

we want to do it for testing

we plan to use the command

```
ssh-keygen -R Linux_box1
```

in case ssh return the issue about `REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED`

is it possible to cause this on remote machine?

Answer (score 0):

Just alter slightly the key of the machine (replace a character) or replace it with a bogus key in the local `known_hosts` file. This will make SSH complain as requested.

Comment: I did it and still not get the message about WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!    ( I did it on source machine and change in known_host one of the characters )